# Get Largest Inscribed Rectangle of a Concave Polygon

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, polygons

I'm looking for an algorithm to find a set of largest inscribed rectangles of a concave polygon where each rectangle must be collinear with one of the edges of the polygon.

In other words, I want to continually cut my polygon down using rectangles until I am left with regions were the largest-inscribed rectangle is not sharing an edge with the original polygon.

Is there a known algorithm for this?

An example:

[image]

This post is related to another post: [Covering a Polygon with Rectangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105164)

I am hoping to split up the questions so I can attract better answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $P$ be your polygon, $e$ an edge of $P$.  I will interpret one aspect
of your question
as seeking all the maximal rectangles with one side flush with each $e$, 
each rectangle $R$ maximal in the sense that 
(a) $R \subset P$ but 
(b) there is no other rectangle $R' \subset P$ with $R' \supset R$.
If you can solve this for one edge $e$, you can iterate over all $n$ edges of $P$.

     [image: Rectangles in a polygons]

Fix $e$ to be horizontal (by rotating $P$).  Now your problem is to find the maximal
axis-aligned rectangles flush with $e$.
It is clear that $R$ is maximal only if all four sides of $R$ cannot be moved to enlarge
$R$.  The edge $e$ determines one side, so there are three to be blocked by $P$ from
enlargement.  A side of $R$ can be blocked by a vertex of $P$ lying in its interior,
or two sides can be blocked by their common corner resting on an edge of $P$. Various
possibilities are shown above.
A naive $O(n^3)$ algorithm can search through all possible blockers for the three sides,
yielding an $O(n^4)$ algorithm over all edges of $P$.
From among these, you could select, e.g., those with largest area, or largest perimeter, or whatever criterion is relevant to your application.

This naive algorithm can be considerably sped up.  A series of papers led to
an $O(n \log^2 n)$ algorithm, which I think might still be the best available.
Whether it would be worth implementing all the tricks necessary to reach this low time complexity
is another question.

 [image: Daniels Fig.1]

> K. Daniels, V. Milenkovic, and D. Roth. Finding the largest area axis-parallel
>   rectangle in a polygon. *Comput. Geom. Theory Appl.*, 7:125-148, 1997.
>   ([CiteSeer link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.47.3370))  Fig.1 shown above.

To address how to "continually cut [your] polygon down" requires some criterion to chose among
all the options.  What I describe above is just a start,
identifying all the maximal rectangles.
I suspect any choice you make will lead to an NP-hard problem, and you'll be forced into
heuristics or approximation algorithms.

One heuristic is the greedy algorithm.  Find, say, the largest-area maximal rectangle $R$ in $P$.
Create several new polygons by subtracting $R$: $P \setminus R$.  Recurse on the pieces.
This would be easy to implement, and equally easy to thwart. :-)

---

Here is what I meant by thwarting the greedy algorithm:

     [image: Greedy vs. Non]
Because no definition of what constitutes an optimal coverage by these rectangles has
been detailed, I cannot prove the greedy algorithm fails to achieve optimality.
But I am convinced that any reasonable definition of optimality will not always
be achieved by the greedy algorithm.

Comment: At first I didn't understand how the greedy algorithm might be easy to thwart. Now, I'll verture to take a guess: By greedy, we are considering the rectangle which maximizes my value for the first edge. If this is true, I would need to change that to iterate over all edges choosing the rectangle which maximizes my value before subtraction.

(By the way, is this problem called Largest Empty Rectangle?)

Comment: Also, I am a bit confused how to describe a function to conclusively maximize my rectangle's value when a corner is constrained by an edge instead of two vertices. Would this be a good approach? Take E and extend it until it intersects with two other edges of P. Then, orthogonal to E at each end find two new points, where each point lies on an edge of P or the edges connecting those points to E or to each other is constrained by a vertex of P.

Comment: Also, to ensure that my extension of E does not intersect P by leaving P, is proximity a good check? In other words, if E intersects P more than two times, I should check the proximity of those intersections to the original end points of E.

Comment: @JoshC: 1st question: See my added examples above re thwarting the greedy algorithm.  2nd question: When two adjacent corners are both constrained by edges, there is a continuum of maximal rectangles, from which you could select, say, the maximal area rectangle. 3rd question: You need a Boolean function that returns `True` iff rectangle $R \subset P$.

Comment: Is there a name for an algorithm which subrtracts R from P?

Comment: @Josh: Usually just called *difference*, or *set subtraction*, among algorithms called *Boolean operations*.