# Algorithm to dissect a polygon into a minimum amount of rectangles, conditioned on a maximum overlap

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

I have the following problem, I have a problem regarding concave polygons. I want to write code to cover any polygon with a minimum amount of rectangles that are allowed to overlap and have no fixed dimension (so it is not like here [Covering a polygon with rectangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105164/covering-a-polygon-with-rectangles)). The rectangles are allowed to be outside the polygon. There should be a trade off between number of polygons used and (total rectangle area / polygon area), obviously I don't want to just lay one humongous rectangle over the whole polygon.
I am sorry, I am not a mathematician, I hope the problem is well defined!

Here an image of one polygon:
[image]
Here with the added rectangles for illustrations.
[image]

Is there any paper that discusses a problem like this? Do you have any suggestions of where/ how to start?

Comment: This problem is hard even covering an orthogonal polygon with axis-parallel rectangles. So you have to use approximation algorithms. You might look at this paper, even though it only addresses the restrictions I mentioned: Kumar, VS Anil, and H. Ramesh. "Covering rectilinear polygons with axis-parallel rectangles." *SIAM Journal on Computing* 32, no. 6 (2003): 1509-1541. Use Google Scholar to see the 34 papers that cite this one.

Comment: As you say, there's a trade-off between number and total area of the rectangles, but you're going to have to decide just what trade-off you're willing to make in order to get an answer to the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson One can phrase the problem as, given $n$, find the covering that uses exactly $n$ rectangles and has minimum area. This problem can be tackled mathematically, and the decision about exactly how to pick $n$ can be delegated to the user.